# Leave a Zoom meeting using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, zoom

I have a Stream Deck and want to be able to hit a button and leave my current Zoom meeting.

There's a [Stream Deck plugin for Zoom](https://lostdomain.org/stream-deck-plugin-for-zoom/) that I use, but when I hit the button to leave a meeting (and am the meeting host) it kills the meeting for everyone.

So I decided to try to script it using AppleScript. While I'm a software engineer, I haven't used AppleScript extensively yet, so I need some help. I'm also hoping if we do find a solution that it can help others.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    tell application "zoom.us"
        activate
        
        
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "w" using {command down}
        end tell
        
        -- Click the "Leave Meeting" button if it exists
        try
            tell application "System Events"
                -- If the "Leave Meeting" button doesn't exist, click the "End Meeting" button
                tell process "zoom.us"
                    -- show an alert with the name of the button
                    display dialog (name of button 1 of window 1 of application process "zoom.us")
                    -- click button "End Meeting" of window 1
                end tell
                
                -- If it then pops up a dialog, click Assign and Leave
                tell process "zoom.us"
                    display dialog (name of button 1 of window 1 of application process "zoom.us")
                    -- click button "Assign and Leave" of window 1
                end tell
            end tell
        on error errMsg number errorNumber
            display dialog "An unknown error occurred:  " & errMsg & " - Number: " & errorNumber as text
        end try
        
    end tell
    
    return input
```

However, this doesn't quite work -- it shows an error which says:

```
An unknown error occurred:
  System Events got an error:
  Can’t make name of button 1 of window 1 of application process "zoom.us" of process "zoom.us" into type string.
  Number: -1700
```

Because Zoom gives you different buttons based on whether you're the host or not, I'm not sure how to navigate this.

Anyone else able to test this and help get it figured out? I'll post a solution if I find one, but thought it would be helpful to get other ideas.

Comment: You'd have to choose who to make host once you leave. How would you do that programmatically?

Comment: It pre-selects the first person (which I really don't care about, since these are internal company meetings), so just being able to click the big red button "Assign and Leave" would work best.